# catch handler in promise chain not capturing the error

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

My code is a simple fetch example which works when the correct resource URL is provided. But when i misspell the  resource name, i was expecting the error to be trapped in the catch block but that didnt happen. The console records an error 
 "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)

My code is

```
      fetch('coffee.jpg')
                .then(response => response.blob())
                .then(blob => {

                    let myURL =  URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    let img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.src = myURL;
                    document.body.appendChild(img);

                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log(" Error fetching file -  " + err.message);
                });
```

Comment: fetch doesn't reject on non-2xx status.

Comment: Check the status of the response before you try to access the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an error handler middleware like this:

```
function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

fetch('coffee.jpg')
  .then(handleErrors)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {

    let myURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = myURL;
    document.body.appendChild(img);

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(" Error fetching file -  " + err.message);
  });
```

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205255) after 5 mins to help future users too. Thanks!